# String prototype in header requires iostream?

Tags: c++

So in my header i made a string: `string s;` The compiler freaks out at this. I know that string is part of iostream::std. Do I have to include it in the header instead of in the .cpp file then? If so is it bad if other files that use the header include iostream? How do I deal with that?

Edit: Also for vector since it seems I'll be needing it a lot in my assignment.

Edit2: I remember seeing #ifndef in a lot of examples of headers and I feel like it may help with my question, but I can't seem to find a good explanation.

Comment: string is a part of `std::string`

Comment: As for Edit2, those are include guards, and completely unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string` and `vector` are separate from `iostream`, and all three are part of the `std` namespace.  You just have to properly qualify them in your header files.

Assignment.h

```
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>
 // no need to #include <iostream>

 struct Obj
 {
    // fully qualified with std::
    std::string s_;

    // same:
    std::vector<std::string> v_;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ok to include headers in other headers if you need them and don't create cyclic dependencies. This is not the case here, since `<string>` is not a user generated header.

What would be bad is if you added `using namespace std;` to your header instead of specifying the scope of your types. Doing this populates your global namespace with the contents of `namespace std` in all files you include your header in.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you do need to include the header for `string` if you are using it in your own header. This is because the compiler needs to calculate the memory layout of the object which has a `string` member, which means it needs to calculate the layout of `string` first, which means it has to see the full declaration of `string`.

There's no direct way around this, but if it's a problem for you you can work around it by using the [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl_idiom#C.2B.2B). One of the benefits of this pattern is that it allows you to aggregate an object in your class without having the need to include its declaration first (forward-declaring that class instead) like this:

```
class std::string; // forward declaration

class my_class
{
    std::string* psz;
};
```

Of course now you are responsible for constructing a `string` and getting a pointer to it yourself, and also managing that object manually. In addition, accessing that string will now require an additional pointer dereference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to include `<string>` because `std::string` is actually a `typedef` for `basic_string` template.

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

If it were a class, you could forward declare it in some cases without including it's definition.

```
class string;
```